# Maven: Define SuperPOM property project.build.directory over command line

Tags: maven

I am building my maven project with GitLab CI on a docker file.
I would like to configure my pipeline with a "compile" stage and a "test" stage. To be able to do that, I need to set the property `project.build.directory`, which is defined in the maven super POM, to the docker cache so the compiled artefact does not get lost between the jobs.

`project.build.directory` is a predefined maven property. Therefore I would think that I am able define it with the CL parameter `-Dproject.build.directory=anotherDir`. This somehow does not work and my project still gets built to the default directory `target`.

If I modify my POM with

```
<properties>
    <buildDir>target</buildDir>
</properties>
<build>
    <directory>${buildDir}</directory>
</build>
```

and call `mvn clean install -DbuildDir=customTargetDir`, my project gets built to the  `customTargetDir` as expected.

Why is that? I really don't see a difference. I both cases, I define the value of an existing property.

Comment: Why are you separating the life cycle which does not really makese sense...Just build it via `mvn clean package` and let `docker build ..` copy the resulting jar/war file being copied into the docker image...Furthermore what about using docker maven plugin (fabricio / spotify) ?

Comment: By separating these stages, I immediately see if the compilation or testing was the problem, which let the pipeline fail. A docker maven plugin will add a lot of extra configuration. My main question is, why can't I override a property from the command line, which is available from the super pom?

Comment: You will see the difference between build error (compile errors) or test failures..Test failures will result in a different state of the pipeline than build error. There is no need to manually separate the life cycle of Maven (apart from that it is not possible)...

Comment: My pipeline currently is `failed` for both. Compilation error and test error. I do not have different states. Is this a special setting?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, for future readers :)

Maven does not provide the ability to override `project.build.directory` (which is `target` by default) from CLI, so smth like `-Dproject.build.directory` is not possible.

However, what this code does:

```xml
<build>
    <directory>${buildDir}</directory>
</build>
```

is exactly what you want - it changes the output directory of the project, so yes it does what exactly is expected.